The splash screen isn't centering exactly according to the screen size
I'm using Custom Tkinter to create a splash screen. I wanted to center the splash screen both horizontally and vertically. I tried the following code, but it didn't work. The splash screen is not exactly centered. I've also attached a screenshot. Please check it and let me know your suggestions. Thanks!
    splash_screen = CTK.CTk()
    splash_screen.overrideredirect(True)

    screen_width = splash_screen.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = splash_screen.winfo_screenheight()

    
    splash_width = int(0.29 * screen_width)
    splash_height = int(0.31 * screen_height)

    splash_image = CTK.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open('splash_image.jpg'),size =(splash_width,splash_height))
    splash_image_lable  = CTK.CTkLabel(splash_screen,image=splash_image,text='')
    splash_image_lable.pack(fill=CTK.BOTH, expand=True)

    x = (screen_width//2) - (splash_width//2)
    y =  (screen_height//2) - (splash_height//2)

    geometry = f"{int(splash_width)}x{int(splash_height)}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}" 

    splash_screen.geometry(geometry)



Have you verified that the screen width and height have been returned correctly? Have you verified that the geometry string you’ve computed is correct?

You code works fine in my Windows 11 with Python 3.12.3.  The window is put at the center of my monitor.

@acw1668 Oh, that's nice. Do you have any idea why it does not work on my computer?

@Byan Oakley  Yes bro

@user8 May be you have a system display scaling not 100%.

@acw1668 Yes bro. That's the reason. My system scaling was 125%. Now fine Thanks
